# rails 3.2.8 ruby 1.9.x tinymce-rails ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, tinymce

I am trying to use tiny-mce WYSIWYG editor with active-admin in my rails 3.2.8 application. After including:

```
gem 'tinymce-rails'
```

(https://github.com/spohlenz/tinymce-rails)

in my Gemfile i get the following error when trying to launch 'webbrick' or 'thin' server or even rails console:

```
    /home/pablo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/tinymce-rails-3.5.7/lib/tinymce/rails/configuration.rb:88:in `<module:Rails>': uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess (NameError)
from /home/pablo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/tinymce-rails-3.5.7/lib/tinymce/rails/configuration.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/pablo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/tinymce-rails-3.5.7/lib/tinymce/rails.rb:5:in `require'
from /home/pablo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/tinymce-rails-3.5.7/lib/tinymce/rails.rb:5:in `<module:Rails>'
from /home/pablo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/tinymce-rails-3.5.7/lib/tinymce/rails.rb:2:in `<module:TinyMCE>'
from /home/pablo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/tinymce-rails-3.5.7/lib/tinymce/rails.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/pablo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/tinymce-rails-3.5.7/lib/tinymce-rails.rb:1:in `require'
from /home/pablo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/tinymce-rails-3.5.7/lib/tinymce-rails.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/pablo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
from /home/pablo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
from /home/pablo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
from /home/pablo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
from /home/pablo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
from /home/pablo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
from /home/pablo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler.rb:128:in `require'
from /home/pablo/Programming/railsy/tiny_mce_trial/config/application.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/pablo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
from /home/pablo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /home/pablo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
from /home/pablo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I managed to reproduce the error on a fresh rails application so I don't think it is a dependency problem. It happens both with ruby 1.9.3 and ruby 1.9.2.

I tried to add:

```
require 'tinymce-rails'
```

In application.rb, enviorment.rb and initializer files but it does not solve the problem.

Any clues ?

Comment: Can you post your entire Gemfile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it already.

Looks like there is a bug in the newest 3.5.7 version. It only came out yesterday.

Installing the previous version:

```
gem install tinymce-rails -v 3.5.6

gem 'tinymce-rails', '3.5.6'
```

Fixed it.